# How to use AS3 draw something and display on android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4

I have a Flex mobile project with a .mxml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               applicationDPI="160">
    <fx:Script> 
        <![CDATA[ 
            import com.djar.Test; 
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void 
            { 
                var d:Test = new Test(); 
            } 
        ]]> 
    </fx:Script> 

    <fx:Declarations> 
    </fx:Declarations> 
    <s:Button x="0" y="0" label="click" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/> 
</s:Application>
```

And the .as file:

```
package com.djar
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.*;

    public class Test extends Sprite
    {
        public var myText:TextField = new TextField();
        public function Test()
        {
            trace("1111111111");
            myText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            myText.text = "HELLO，MY FLASH";
            var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            myFormat.size = 40;
            myFormat.font = "Cooper Black";
            myFormat.color = 0xcc0000;
            myText.x=0
            myText.y=50
            myText.setTextFormat(myFormat);
            trace("2222222222");
            addChild(myText);
        }
    }
}
```

When I debug and click the button on my phone, I can see `1111111111` and `2222222222` in the console, but nothing happens on my phone. What should I do to make it show `HELLO，MY FLASH`?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are adding `myText` as a child of your `Test` `Sprite`, however you are not adding that `Sprite` to the `stage`. This can be addressed in your button handler.

```
 protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void 
 { 
     var d:Test = new Test();
     addChild(d);
 }
```